# How can I speed up learning for feed forward, gradient based backpropagation neural networks

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, backpropagation, gradient-descent

I am using tanh as an activation function.
Let's take one problem for example.

```
XOR Problem:

1   1   0
0   1   1
1   0   1
0   0   0
```

When I train my neural network 500 epochs,
results look like this:

```
1   1   0.001015
0   1   0.955920
1   0   0.956590
0   0   0.001293
```

After another 500 epoch:

```
1   1   0.000428
0   1   0.971866
1   0   0.971468
0   0   0.000525
```

Another 500 epoch:

```
1   1   0.000193
0   1   0.980982
1   0   0.981241
0   0   0.000227
```

It seems that the learning is slowing down alot.
My neural network is taking forver to get precise enough for my costom problems.

Is there anyway to speed up the learning after it starts getting slow like that?

Thanks

Comment: do you have any activation in the output layer? what is your learning method? parameters used? you should include whole code

Comment: Which loss function are you using? cross-entropy? Mean Squared Error?

Answer (score 1):

This kind of learning curve is perfectly normal in neural network training (or even in [real life learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Learning_curve)). That said, while the general shape of the curve is typical, we can improve on its steepness. In that respect, I suggest that you implement [momentum](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8yg2mRJx-z4) into your training algorithm. If that does not seem to be enough, your next step would be to implement some adaptive learning rate algorithm such as [adadelta, adagrad or rmsprop](http://sebastianruder.com/optimizing-gradient-descent/). Finally, a last thing you may want to try is [batch normalization](http://arxiv.org/abs/1502.03167).

Comment: How could i apply adadelta to my simple c++ neural network?
I was unable to cause I simple don't understand math language that well.

Answer (score 0):

If the net you are building has sigmoids applied to the neurons in the output layer (seems like they do from your results), you might consider removing them and just have a linear relation. Your net might become a bit more unstable, so a smaller step-size can be advised. But you will be able to reach better accuracy.